# How is my SEO affected if I make all outbound links on my website rel=nofollow?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, googlebot

We have a lot of outbound links on our website to various high DA websites.

Would it help or damage our SEO if I make all of the links `rel=nofollow`?

Comment: SEO juice doesn't leak out as it used too, time to ditch those 1999's SEO guides and read something current. Use nofollow for untrusted 3rd party websites, and use full juice for links that credit is due and revelant.

Comment: As well, I got it somewhere that one of the red-flag factors for detecting spam sites is all outbound links are nofollow (right or wrong). Under normal circumstances, no site should have all nofollow links, however, it seems that some spamdexing sites do.

Comment: Got it thanks, will definitely not be making this mistake in that case.

Comment: There are too many myths come out, if you look out deeply to understand how PR flow to internal links or external links. 
Simon@PR passed though external links as well, john muller was said, in one of hangout video. @Ratan, if you use nofollow links, then your PR will be scuplt read out matt cutts blog post for more information @Closetnoc@ There are many of website like twitter, fb, wikipedia using nofollow in all links, so there is no any problem to use nofollow in all links, John also said, we did not penalize any site who using nofollow in all external links.

Comment: @Goyllo I can see how what I wrote can be misread. I was not saying that all nofollow external links result in a penalty. Not even close. However, I did say that it was a red-flag, meaning a potential indicator, for a spam site. I also hinted an opinion with my (right or wrong) comment. It is true that under normal circumstances that no site should have all nofollow external links, however, I can see how your examples would. That makes sense. Good info!

Answer (score 3):

First, there's no reason to `nofollow` outbound links unless they're from unmoderated user-generated content (i.e. people could link to things you'd rather they didn't) or they've been paid for.

Second, only this week [a fairly thorough study](http://www.rebootonline.com/blog/long-term-outgoing-link-experiment) established that not only is linking out not damaging to your SEO, it's *beneficial*.

Comment: Your two points contradict each other. Also, the linked-to article doesn't evaluate no-follow, only not linking at all.

Comment: Those don't seem contradictory to me at all.

Comment: Case study is created by marketer not by seo expert, He don't know, how crawling, indexing and ranking work by Google. If external link is ranking factor, then I will create all of anchor link when Google keywords encounter in my webpage. We don't need to create this type of case study, only few question can prove that, external link is not part of ranking factor or it does not help in ranking.

Comment: You should also `nofollow` any links that are paid-for.

Comment: @w3dk Good point. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

All outbound links rel=nofollow?
This is common question that arouses in mind of those who avail [SEO marketing services](http://ficode.com/services/search-engine-marketing-london/)
There can be only one reason to do so and that is you are linking to all spammy sites on which you do not trust. So this may give a hint to Google that you are doing spam. Which i think will not be good for your SEO.
So use rel=nofollow only where it is necessary, and use rel=dofollow for trusted sites.

Answer (score 1):

**It does not affect whether you used nofollow attribute or not. But it is always good practice to moderate your outbound links. If you linked to good resources without nofollow attribute, then google crawl and pass PR to that URL, so that useful information rise up in search result.**

If you used links without nofollow attribute, then Google pass-out some values to that link. There are many of webmaster disagree with me, But recently John muller said, we pass same/equaly PR to internally and externally links.

If you used links with nofollow attribute, then your PR will not be save, it will be [sculpt](https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/pagerank-sculpting/). For example, you have webpage A, and there are only 5 outbound links, and 2 of them using nofollow attribute, then remaining 3 links gain only 1 PR, and your 2 PR will be sculpt. (Here we not used other factors link dumping factor for clear PR calculation).