# Is it non-beneficial for my website if I pass do follow link to another website?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, links

If I provide outbound link to a similar niche website with do-follow tag, that website will sure be benefitted but will it harm my website in any ways ?

Comment: See also: [How is my SEO affected if I make all outbound links on my website rel=nofollow?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90535/how-is-my-seo-affected-if-i-make-all-outbound-links-on-my-website-rel-nofollow) and [What needs to be done to user generated outbound links to prevent hurting SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112769/what-needs-to-be-done-to-user-generated-outbound-links-to-prevent-hurting-seo)